# How to remove navbar bottom padding in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I am trying to get a bottom navbar on to my website the issue that keeps arising is that their is some padding on the bottom of the page that I cannot seem to remove. You can see the code for the navbar below.

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Falke Homepage </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

     <!-- Loading Bootstrap -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- Loading Flat UI -->
    <link href="css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">

    <!-- Loading Custom Stylesheet-->
    <link href="css/Stylesheet for Homepage.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>     
<body>
    <!-- Static Navbar For Top of Homepage-->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role ="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="nav navbar-nav">
                <ul class = "nav">
                    <li><img src="img/Falke Logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>  
                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <div class='btn-group'>
                        <li><button class="btn navbar-btn btn-info">Sign In</button></li> 
                    </div>
                    <div class='btn-group'>
                        <li><button class="btn navbar-btn btn-success">Register</button></li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>                  
    </div><!-- end of navbar-->

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <img src="img/NYC Skyline.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image">
            </div><!-- pic of NYC -->
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                     <h1>Welcome to Falke!</h1>
                        <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
                     <a href="#" class="btn btn-large btn-info">Get Started</a>
                </div><!-- end of jumbotron-->

    </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"><img src ="img/Biker.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6"><p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p></div>
            </div>
    </div><!--  End of Biker image and Text container -->

    <!-- Static Navbar For Bottom of Homepage-->




    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-bottom footer" role ="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class = "nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><img src="img/Facebook Flat.png" class='footer-img' alt="Responsive image" ></li>
                    <li><img src="img/Twitter Flat.png"  class='footer-img'alt="Responsive image"> </li>
                    <li><img src="img/YouTube Flat.png" class="footer-img" alt="Responsive image"> </li>
                    <li><img src="img/Google Plus Flat.png" class='footer-img' alt="Responsive image"> </li>
                    <li><img src="img/Instagram Flat.png" class='footer-img' alt="Responsive image"> </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <div class='btn-group'>
                        <button class="btn navbar-btn btn-link">About Us</button>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </div><!-- end of navbar for bottom-->


    <!-- Load JS here for greater good =============================-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-switch.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flatui-checkbox.js"></script>
    <script src="js/flatui-radio.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tagsinput.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see the issue here[image: Padding Issue]

I'm using Bootstrap 3 thanks for the help.

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle/bootply example, or link to your website. Otherwise it's difficult to help you.

Comment: falkeapp.com is the url. Thanks.

Comment: can you post the complete code?

Comment: Posted the complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `About us` is 68px high, while the footer should only be 53px. Decrease the padding on `.navbar-nav > li > a`in flat-ui.css on line 4729.
Next, remove the `margin-bottom`on flat-ui.css on line 4594 and in bootstrap.css on line 3649.

Comment: Hey so I forgot to push my update to the server I changed the About Us to a button that fits within the footer. Would those changes still apply?

Comment: Concerning the `margin-bottom`: Yes.

Comment: I will advice not to change default bootstrap.css instead override it in your css.

Comment: Alternatively you might consider to just change the `margin-bottom` in the flat-ui.css to just `0`.

Comment: Thanks guys I just overrode the margins in my css file!